# Why does calculation of magnetic moment of electron depend on mass?

Tags: electrons, mass, magnetic-moment

All of the calculations I have seen for the magnetic moment of electrons include the electron's mass in the calculation.  Why would this be relevant?  The calculation for magnetism of macroscopic objects depends only on magnitude of charge and motion thereof.  Where does mass come into play?

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic moment is expressed in terms of the spin angular momentum, which is proportional to mass. Magnetic moment is instead proportional to charge. Hence there is a factor q/m in its expression.